# SpringBoot add static custom folder

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, static, staticresource

I'm using SpringBoot 2.1.3. I would like to save some file inside a static folder to access it simply by:

```
localhost:8080/[filename]
```

By default Spring boot serves static content from one of the following locations in the classpath:

```
1) /static
2) /public
3) /resources
4) /META-INF/resources
```

In effect if I create the public folder inside my project classpath:

[image]

and put a file.txt inside it, starting application I can visualize the file with the above path.

Googling around I find out how add a custom static folder in two ways. First one by *application.properties*:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/documents/
```

but even if I have created the *documents* folder in the same place where public folder is, I cannot reach the file with the path:

```
localhost:8080/[filename]
```

The second way is by java @Bean configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class AppConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 @Bean
 WebMvcConfigurer configurer () {
    return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers (ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/pages/**").
                      addResourceLocations("classpath:/documents/");
        }
    };
 }
}
```

and now if I try to get my resource with:

```
localhost:8080/pages/[filename]
```

doesn't work at all..

Any hint??

Thank you all

Comment: classpath: points to src\main\resources

Comment: Thank you. it was enough write _spring.resources.static-locations=/documents/_ and it works.. but now the problem is that this directive overwrite others static default folders. I can't reach anymore all the others folder than I think I will use the default ones.